# QtCharts in qml with pyqt6 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, charts, qt-quick, pyqt6

I want show charts in my app with Python back-end and qml front-end but I got an error.

Import:

```
import QtCharts 2.3
```

Error:

```
module "QtCharts" is not installed
```

I installed qtcharts with maintaince.exe

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In PyQt6 the chart module comes in a separate package and you must run:

```py
python -m pip install PyQt6-Charts PyQt6
```

On the other hand maintaince.exe only works for C++ so installing QtCharts does not affect PyQt6.

In the next part there is a demo:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(
        handle_object_created, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection
    )
    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtCharts

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Login Page")

    ChartView {
        id: chartView

        anchors.fill: parent

        LineSeries {
            XYPoint {
                x: 0
                y: 0
            }

            XYPoint {
                x: 1.1
                y: 2.1
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Note: In Qt6 the versions of the QML modules should not be indicated.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i used it and i installed but error is the same still !

Comment: i looked C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyQt6 folder but i can't see any QtCharts file. may this be problem?

Comment: @user17312099 Is vscode using the same python you used to install `PyQt6-Charts`? Execute `python main.py` from console/CMD